# Can I insert mean values for dummies when predicting an average person in a logistic regression model?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I have a logistic regression model with several dummy variables. I would like to predict the probability of Y for "an average person in the dataset". However, how do I do this when I have explanatory variables like "male", "education level_high", "education level_med" etc.? Can I insert an average value for dummies and use this as "an average person"? This would mean that an average person e.g. would be $0.54$ Male..

For instance, I have the following model:
$Y = 0.57 -0.97$Male$ + 1.2$Education_level_high $+\dots$

If I want to predict Y for an average person, is it then ok to just insert averages for dummies? This would be:
$Y = 0.57 - 0.97 \times 0.54 + 1.2 \times 0.76$

Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Unless you are suggesting inserting a single, constant value, e.g., 0.54, for all respondents in your data (which, obviously, would not work) technically it wouldn't matter for the regression. The resulting parameters, however, would have a different interpretation from a 0,1 variable. Dummy variables are meant to capture qualitative distinctions in behavior which, by definition, express the average value or proportion of the sample for which that dummy is true.

Answer (score 1):

This is along-discussed issue when presenting results for logit models.

On one hand, the short answer to your question is "yes" - you can hold dummy variables at their mean values and the model will give you a prediction for a person with these characteristics. There is no "mathematical" problem with holding "female" at "0.56" or whatever.

This is in fact the approach used when calculating the "marginal effect at the mean" - another way of quantifying effect sizes for logit models. This approach tells us how a one unit increase in each X variable changes the probability of Y, holding all other X variables at their mean values. And this approach will give you a pretty good sense of the "average" effect of each X variable on Y.

On the other hand, what does it actually *mean* to hold female at 0.56? You say you want to predict the effect for an average person but *no* person has a gender of "0.56" so the prediction you generate will not be applicable to *any* actual person in the dataset (even non-binary gender people...who are either missing from the analysis or identified with another dummy variable). If gender is a significant predictor in the model, then any *real" person in the dataset is going to have a Y value that is bigger or smaller than the one you just predicted.

So what do we do about this? One strategy, which another post flagged, is to hold dummy variables at their *modal* values. That definitely avoids the issues above, and it's something I've often done. However, if (say) 56% of your dataset is female, then the modal category leaves out almost half of the sample. Another approach would be to generate two predictions - one for males and one for females (holding continuous variables at their mean) but this is unwieldy if you have lots of dummies in the model. You could also hold independent variables at the most "substantively important" values - even if they are not the modal ones. Whatever does the best job of telling the "story" of the model.

This doesn't help you if you want to predict Y for specific types of people, but another approach for estimating the *effect size* for different variables is called the "average marginal effect": in this approach we basically step through the entire dataset and estimate, for each observation, how the probability of Y changes when we increment one X variable by one while holding all the other X variables at *whatever value they were already at for that observation*. So you get one measure of effect size for each person, and then you average them all up. This gets you the "average" effect of each variables for this dataset. This way we get an "average" measure of effect size without printing that some people have fractional values for binary variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case it makes sense to use

- mean values for continuous variables
- modal (most frequent) values for each categorical variable (watch out for ties).

Otherwise your average person might wind up a statistical Frankenstein, like [Johnny Cash's stolen Cadillac](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18cW_yHo3PY).

Some statistical packages set the baseline category to be the modal category for categorical variables, which makes things easier for you since you can just ignore those terms when you let software handle the dummy variable creation rather than doing it manually.

Also, don't forget to wrap the index function inside the inverse logit function
$$\Lambda()=\frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+...+\beta_px_p} }{1+e^{\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+...+\beta_px_p} }$$ to get back to probabilities.

This would make your prediction 0.72 instead of 0.96 (sticking to your original choice of covariate values).